Cannot start Ubuntu on WSL2
have a W10 device in test environment with clean WSL2 install, no distros. Installed Ubuntu. When attempting to launch I receive the error:
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80072749
Error: 0x80072749 A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.
When this happens the Windows vmcompute service crashes
Interestingly, I have a different W10 device in our production environment and DO NOT get this error, altho the firewall there has yet to be configured explicitly for WSL to work (i.e in prod Unbuntu launches ok, but cannot ping google, not concerned about that right now). Anyway, I suspect some other firewall differences already exist between test and prod, but cannot spot any suspect rules. Any ideas, advice would be welcome. Many thanks.
Simon
